# a simple question

Tags: calculus, matrices

I have an inequality:
$$2ax^2+by^2\geq0$$that $x^2\geq y^2$.  Actually $x^2$ is $c.c$ that is $(\sum c_{ij}^2)$ and $y^2$ is  $(tr(c))^2$, where $c$ is $2\times 2$ matrix.

Now, I want to show that $a$ and $a+b$ are  positive.
Maybe it is so simple, but it got alot of time of me.

Please help me,
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $x=2,y=1 a=.5 b=-1$ then $(.5)2^2-1=2 \geq 0$ but $a+b=-.5 < 0$ so its not true.

Comment: @Martin No, as stated in the question, $x$ and $y$ are numbers, not matrices. When $c=\pmatrix{1&\sqrt{3/2}\\ \sqrt{3/2}&0}$, we have $x^2:=\sum c_{ij}^2=4$ and $y^2=1$, so that baharampuri's example applies.

Comment: @user1551: right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

May be not. If $c$ is $(0)$, then $a$ and $b$ are equal to 0. They are not positive.

Comment: $c$ is not $\bf 0$

Comment: Why? From your question, $c$ may be is a 0 matrix.

Comment: @Hakhak It doesn't matter whether $c$ is the zero matrix or not. If $a=b=0$, the inequality $2ax^2+by^2\ge0$ always holds. In other words, you cannot infer that $a>0$ or $a+b>0$ from the inequality.

Comment: Sorry,I should say it that $c$,$a$ and $b$ are physics concepts that are not zero, but I do not know any more about them.